# Making a string from a listbox

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, listbox

I have 2 projects, one which has a highscorelist stored on it, and one which tries to add highscores to that list and retrieve all items on the list. Trying to put items on the list works good, but retrieving the list doesn't work well. Here's the code:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Main

Dim server As New TcpListener(45888)
Dim client As New TcpClient
Dim stream As NetworkStream
Dim connected As Boolean

Private Sub cmd_start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmd_start.Click
    server.Start()
    cmd_start.Enabled = False
    cmd_stop.Enabled = True
    lbl_status.Text = "Running"
    lbl_status.ForeColor = Color.Green
    tmr.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub cmd_stop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmd_stop.Click
    server.Stop()
    cmd_start.Enabled = True
    cmd_stop.Enabled = False
    lbl_status.Text = "Not running"
    lbl_status.ForeColor = Color.Red
    tmr.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connected = False
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
End Sub

Dim x As Integer = 0

Private Sub tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmr.Tick
    If server.Pending Then
        client = server.AcceptTcpClient()
        stream = client.GetStream()
        tmr.Stop()
        read()
    Else
        tmr.Start()
    End If
    lbl_mseconds.Text = "Relative time: " & x
    x += 1
End Sub

Private Sub SendMessage(message As String)
    Dim sendtext() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)
    stream.Write(sendtext, 0, sendtext.Length)
    stream.Flush()
End Sub

Private Sub read()
    Dim rec(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    stream.Read(rec, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize)
    Dim rectext As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rec)
    If rectext.Contains("@1@") Then
        rectext = rectext.Substring(3)
        If rectext.Split(CChar("-"))(0).Length = 2 Then rectext = "0" & rectext
        If rectext.Split(CChar("-"))(0).Length = 1 Then rectext = "00" & rectext
        listbox_highscores.Items.Add(rectext)
    ElseIf rectext.Contains("@2@") Then
        Dim tosend As String = listbox_highscores.Items(0).ToString
        For i = 1 To listbox_highscores.Items.Count - 1
            tosend &= "," & listbox_highscores.Items(i).ToString
        Next
        MsgBox(tosend)
        SendMessage(tosend)
    End If
    tmr.Start()
End Sub
End Class
```

On the other project I have this:

```
Dim server As New TcpListener(45888)
Dim client As New TcpClient
Dim stream As NetworkStream

Friend Sub sendHighscore(name As String, score As Integer)
    Try
        client.Connect("192.168.1.127", 45888)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    stream = client.GetStream()
    Dim sendtext() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("@1@" & score & "-" & name)
    stream.Write(sendtext, 0, sendtext.Length)
    client = New TcpClient
End Sub

Friend Sub getHighscoreList()
    ListBox_highscores.Items.Clear()
    Try
        client.Connect("192.168.1.127", 45888)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ListBox_highscores.Items.Add("Couldn't connect")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    stream = client.GetStream()
    Dim sendtext() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("@2@")
    stream.Write(sendtext, 0, sendtext.Length)
    client = New TcpClient
    read()
End Sub

Private Sub read()
    Dim rec(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    stream.Read(rec, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize)
    Dim rectext As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rec)
    Label2.Text = rectext
    For Each item In rectext.Split(",")
        ListBox_highscores.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

Then when I use the sub sendHighscore() with a name and score, everything perfectly works and it shows in the other project on the list, but when I use the sub getHighscoreList() the list on the second project only contains the first item from the first list. Does someone has ideas?

Comment: You have two different controls with different names, is it supposed to be that way? You have "listbox_highscores" and also listbox...

Comment: That was a mistake indeed, thanks for that, but that wasn't the problem :(

Comment: see my answer to your issue.

Comment: A little bit shorter: `String.Join(",", listBox.Items.Cast(Of String))`

Comment: @TimSchmelter correct indeed, but wasn't what he was doing at the time. This indeed is better off though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: Original answer removed entirely because it wasn't actually the problem (although it  did offer improvements). My answer was nearly identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26329263/242584) anyway.*

After analyzing this project much more closely, the problem with the For..Next loop not returning the expected results is because the strings are being sent back and forth as byte arrays in buffers much larger than necessary (`client.ReceiveBufferSize`). The actual "strings" received contain large amounts of non-printable characters (garbage) added to the end to fill the buffer. The quick and dirty solution is to remove all non-printable characters:

```
rectext = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(rectext, _
    "[^\u0020-\u007F]", String.Empty)
```

The whole Sub would read like this:

```
Private Sub read()
    Dim rec(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    stream.Read(rec, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize)
    Dim rectext As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rec)
    If rectext.Contains("@1@") Then
        rectext = rectext.Substring(3)
        If rectext.Split(CChar("-"))(0).Length = 2 Then rectext = "0" & rectext
        If rectext.Split(CChar("-"))(0).Length = 1 Then rectext = "00" & rectext
        rectext = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(rectext, "[^\u0020-\u007F]", String.Empty)
        listbox_highscores.Items.Add(rectext)
    ElseIf rectext.Contains("@2@") Then
        Dim tosend As String = listbox_highscores.Items(0).ToString
        For i As Integer = 1 To (listbox_highscores.Items.Count - 1)
            tosend &= "," & listbox_highscores.Items(i).ToString
        Next
        SendMessage(tosend)
    End If
    tmr.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: the OP said that was a mistake, he's got two different components and they are not right, I'm assuming he's only got 1 listbox. If that's the case your concatenation wouldn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work, changed everything to .ToString, but doesn't make a difference

Comment: @Extremelyd1 also please explain "but doesn't make a difference", can you provide more details so we can better assist you?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the change in the question, but I don't understand what the problem is anymore.

Comment: how do you mean? the msgbox at the end returns the same as when I didn't use the .ToString

Comment: What is in your ListBox, and what string does the MsgBox display?

Comment: @Extremelyd1 you have issue's until you can post a screenshot of your issue Im affraid and Im sure that everyone else here is done helping until you can clarify a little more. Your saying it doesn't make a difference and this and that, well explain more. You have more than a few answers that clearly solve your issue as what you needed help with...

Comment: @Extremelyd1 you said it only gives you the first item, well you have answers here that will fix that...

Comment: @MrCoDeXer I updated my question and no, the answers don't fix the problem that it only shows the 1 instead of 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: THEN POST THE STUFF YOU HAVE, you don't make sence! We can't help if you can't provide the stuff your saying isn't correct! I ran both solutions provided we gave you and it WORKS!

Comment: @Extremelyd1 see image I provided. If your having these issues I am sorry you have them, until you can provided better explanation and possibly a screenshot of YOUR ISSUES, I am done helping here...

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR enough explanation?

Comment: @Extremelyd1 The only thing that stands out to me right now is this line `For i = 1 To listbox_highscores.Items.Count - 1` needs to be `For i As Integer = 1 To listbox_highscores.Items.Count - 1` if you're using Option Strict (which you enabled at the top of the file) or it will not compile. I would set a breakpoint on this line and step through the code in the debugger to see if you're getting the results you expect.

Comment: @JustinRyan Fixed that, but doesn't solve the problem. Running it and checking to value of tosend in the loop gives me 1 nothing more, no komma's, nothing.

Comment: After setting your breakpoint and stepping through the code, is the code inside the For...Next loop being executed, or is it passed over?

Comment: That code is being executed but the string 'tosend' doesn't change after it's initial value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit stumped if what you describe is accurate. Unless you're getting strings with trailing commas ("1,,,,") meaning that for some reason it's not pulling items from the ListBox, I don't see how it could be executing `tosend &= "," & listbox_highscores.Items(i).ToString` and _not_ modifying the `tosend` string.

Comment: That is my whole point, why is my code not working, do you have skype or something, where I can show it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your comma's are off as well...

```
  Dim tosend As String = String.Empty
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To listbox.Items.Count - 1
        If intCount >= 1 Then
            tosend &= "," & listbox.Items(i).ToString
        Else
            tosend &= listbox.Items(i).ToString
            intCount += 1
        End If

    Next

    MessageBox.Show(tosend)
```

**Screenshot THAT IT WORKS!**

[image]

Comment: Also only says the first item on the listbox